# Rails I18n Customize Interpolation symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rails-i18n, string-interpolation

I have an app running Rails and Angular, and am using I18n to translate all content. Unfortunately, I'm too far down the road to change the [Angular interpolation symbols](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate), which would have been very easy.

There are instances when I would like to interpolate translations on the Angular side, rather than Rails side.

Is there an easy way to specify to I18n interpolation delimiters to match those of Angular (ie use `{{}}` instead of `%{}`).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? why not change ``%{}`` to ``{{}}``?  Do you use same translations for Rails + Angular?

Comment: Yes, I have the same set of translations available on the server, and then made available through an API to mobile and web.

Comment: Ok just for clarification, do you need the translations on the serverside (in Rails) or are they just for the angular app?

Comment: Both. I have haml templates on the server and angular templates on the client. I want the flexibility and I don't want to have to have multiple translation entries, one for Rails and another for Angular.